# Back to the form with back button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

How does I can make the browser back button resend me the form? I have my page www.example.com/results where I see all results of $_POST search, when I click in one result I load it in www.example.com/result1 . I need to click on the back button and loads the form again without showing "Confirm form Resubmission" (F5). I do not care to do it with PHP, with JS, jQuery.
 
For example:
Index.html

```
 <form method="post" action="results.html">       
  <input type="text" name="findSomething" />
 </form>
```

In results.html show the results:

```
 <a href="result1.html>Result1</a> 
 <a href="result2.html>Result1</a>
 <a href="result3.html>Result1</a>
  .......
```

In result1.html,resutlt2.html.... if a click on back button, brower says that I must to Resubmission the form.

Comment: you can use $_SESSION or $_COOKIE for that ( however i don't understand what do you want )

Comment: use get-post-get redirect pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is default browser functionality ,you can change the setting using PHP only. You can use these syntax in your PHP config file before the session start:

```
<?php

session_cache_limiter ('private, must-revalidate');    
$cache_limiter = session_cache_limiter();
session_cache_expire(60); // in minutes 

?>
```

Now it will be not ask to re-submission the form.